# Entity Framework.При добавлении создается новое поле в родительской таблице

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Есть 2 модели связанные отношением один ко многим.Есть метод, который выполняет операцию добавления

```
var dialog = await repositoryManager.Set<Dialog>()
    .FirstWithIncludesAsync(d => d.Id == dialogId,i => i.Messages);

if (dialog != null)
  {
      var message = new Message()
         {
           Dialog = dialog,
           Content = content,
           UserId = currentId,
           PublishTime = DateTime.Now
         };

  bool isAdded = await repositoryManager.Set<Message>().AddAsync(message);

  if (isAdded)
      {
        Clients.Group(dialogId.ToString()).send(user, content);
      }
 }
```

Объект успешно добавляется в БД, однако, вместе с ним в таблицу Dialogs добавляется новое поле, все значения копируются за исключением Id, и в поле Dialog_Id присваивается Id нового поля.Почему это так происходит, ведь при инициализации я указываю ссылку на существующее поле из БД?

Comment: Что такое repositoryManager?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Класс для управления репозиториями, реализация паттерна UnitOfWork

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос его код

Comment: @АндрейNOP Метод Set() этого класса возвращает экземпляр репозитория, может быть его код предоставить?

Comment: Репозиторий каждый раз заново создаётся? Контекст каждый раз новый создаётся?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Получается так

Comment: Ну дык отсюда и дубли. Если сущность получена в другом контексте, то чтобы ее использовать надо приаттачить

Comment: "Добавляется новое поле" - вы наверное имеете ввиду "новая запись в таблицу, дубликат", а не "новый столбец/поле"?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Благодарю, ваш ответ помог!